# Apply CSS to data-role="page" in jquerymobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have this page

```
<head>
<title>Real Life Achievements</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="frameworks/jquerymobile.css"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="frameworks/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="frameworks/jquerymobile.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", initApp, false);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="start"> 

    ...

</div>
</body>
```

I read [here](http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2011/01/31/top-10-jquery-mobile-code-snippets-that-you-need-to-know/) that I can apply styles for the whole data-role="page" container by doing this

```
.ui-page {
   background: #eee;
}
```

but it doesnt work. My background for the page is always white. I dont want to use JQM styles. How can I apply my body-styles to the jquery mobile "page"?

Comment: Where are you setting this style?

Comment: in the "application.css" file, I added the header

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: as far as i know you need that class applied onto element which you want to have those rules applied to.

Comment: @GnrlBzik JQueryMobile replaces `<div data-role="page">` with `<div class="ui-page">`.

Comment: @saluce, let me rephrase this then, so that my hint is more relevant. Hey dan what if you move data-role to body tag? if you assume that div would fill the width and height of the viewport, check your rules, and see how they apply to html, body and your div element.

Comment: @GnrlBzik That doesn't conform to JQueryMobile framework, then.

Comment: @GnrlBzik, data role to body tag doesnt change it, I will check what the side gets of the css.

Comment: @saluce, what if we skip the conformance with jquery mobile for a second and just look at css it self, i don't have code to look at but. If assumption that div should have background-color:#eee; when .ui-page class is applied but thats not that case, lets then hard code it, and explore the element it self not just to see if background is applied but if block element stretches to fill the area.

Answer (score 2):

`.ui-content` will style the data-role=content area. So for example if you want to style the whole page area you would do this:

```
.ui-content, .ui-page{background: #eee;}
```

Keep in mind you will have to move your css underneath the JQM style sheet as someone else already suggested.

Here is an example of it working http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/7M4Pg/1/

Comment: this only sets the background of the area that contains text, not the entire site

Comment: it´s weird that it applies the background to ui-content, but not to ui-body

Comment: I inserted my code into the side, it works there, but not in my app. Hmmmmmm

Comment: Did you edit your JQM css? Did you add style to the element i.e. `<div data-role="page" style="background:#eee;">`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `application.css` header below the framework css files, because your styles are being overwritten by the framework loading.  Alternatively, you can add `!important` to the background rule, like `background: #eee !important;`, to prevent being overwritten by later stylesheets.

Comment: its much better and holistic to move application.css then start adding !important flag.

Comment: @GnrlBzik Agreed, which is why I listed it as the alternative, not the primary method =)

Comment: I will test it on different phones now.